# Api response as a zip not as JSON

Tags: android, json, api, zip

I am building an Android app and with the help of a remote API I am getting responses to parse into my application. Some of the responses are returned into a zip file (not like the others as JSON) just because of the data are so big. Have you any idea how handle this problem? Should I download the zip file and parse it locally ? (even with my mac I am having trouble to open the file). Is there any special treat with this problem? Should I use other tools than retrofit ?

Comment: can you provide what type of data your getting from that zip file means layout of data ?

Comment: in the zip file there is JSON object that has a lot of informations . What's the best way to do ?